# How to send a file via JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form with a input type file. In that input, I will select only text files.

I would like to know how to send that selected file via JSON/Ajax to my action.

Somebody already worked with it? Sending files through JSON/Ajax.

I am using C# + MVC 3

HERE'S the answer:

http://powerdotnetcore.com/asp-net-mvc/asp-net-mvc-simple-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery

Comment: JSON = JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: Just upload your file and read it inside your controller

Comment: I don't want do post in the form.. I want do it through Ajax @AthibaN

Comment: @DesertIvy why don't you help me instead only giving - votes?

Comment: Just send it using base64

Comment: When I send the post.. the parameter in the Action is nullable. Looks like that there is a specifc way to send files using Ajax

Comment: You cannot send files through JSON. You need to use a partialview and submit only that.

Comment: Check [this Link](http://powerdotnetcore.com/asp-net-mvc/asp-net-mvc-simple-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery) for AJAX upload, and read the file inside your controller if you need so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you mention wanting to use JSON but as for performing file upload with Ajax why not just use the built-in Ajax form since you are useing MVC? A simple example may be like this:

**Model:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required, Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FileExtensions(Extensions = "txt", ErrorMessage = "Specify a txt file.")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div id="result"></div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" } ))    
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.File)
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Use your file here
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            model.File.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        }
    }

    //Return some html back to calling page...
    return PartialView("YourPartialView");

}
```